# Solving linear systems of equations consists of block-diagonal part + small sparse part

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, relaxations

guys i have system of the following form $A*x = b, A = BD+\epsilon * S$ where $BD$ is block-diagonal system , S - some sparse system, $\epsilon$ -- some small constant, for clearity $\lvert\lvert BD \rvert \rvert = \lvert\lvert S \rvert \rvert = 1 $. Dimensions of BD and S are large for me (~10000, solving many times per second, beyond other stuff). I want to solve it like this -- find solution of block-diagonal system $BD^{-1}$, then use it as preconditioner to get new equation ${BD}^{-1}* A* x = {BD}^{-1}*b => (I + \epsilon * {BD}^{-1}* S) * x ={BD}^{-1}*b  $ that i want to solve using some relaxation method like SOR.  So, the questions are following
1. What are pitfails of this method
2. Whether there exists more optimal (in terms of *speed* ) to solve such systems.

Comment: Regarding number 1 - the drawback of any iterative _stationary_ method is that the convergence might be very slow in finite precision arithmetic. An alternative might be a Krylov method such as GMRES or BiCG with preconditioning, or possibly some algebraic multigrid method - however the optimal procedure will heavily depend on the amount of additional information about the matrices and the right-hand side